Mongoose Validation Error on lastUpdated Field Despite Setting It Before Save
I'm running into a bit of an issue with Mongoose in my Node.js/Express application, and I would greatly appreciate your help. The problem occurs when I try to update a Restaurant document in MongoDB. I'm getting a validation error that says the lastUpdated field is required, even though I'm setting it explicitly before saving the document.
Error Message:
error Error: Restaurant validation failed: lastUpdated: Path `lastUpdated` is required.
    at ValidationError.inspect (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:50:26)
    at formatValue (node:internal/util/inspect:806:19)
    at inspect (node:internal/util/inspect:365:10)
    at formatWithOptionsInternal (node:internal/util/inspect:2304:40)
    at formatWithOptions (node:internal/util/inspect:2166:10)
    at console.value (node:internal/console/constructor:338:14)
    at console.log (node:internal/console/constructor:383:61)
    at /opt/render/project/src/dist/controllers/MyRestaurantController.js:81:17
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at rejected (/opt/render/project/src/dist/controllers/MyRestaurantController.js:6:65) {
  errors: {
    lastUpdated: ValidatorError: Path `lastUpdated` is required.
        at validate (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schemaType.js:1385:13)
        at SchemaType.doValidate (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schemaType.js:1369:7)
        at /opt/render/project/src/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:3071:18
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:85:11) {
      properties: [Object],
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'lastUpdated',
      value: undefined,
      reason: undefined,
      [Symbol(mongoose#validatorError)]: true
    }
  },
  _message: 'Restaurant validation failed'
}

Relevant Code:
Mongoose Schema:
const restaurantSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
  restaurantName: { type: String, required: true },
  city: { type: String, required: true },
  country: { type: String, required: true },
  deliveryPrice: { type: Number, required: true },
  estimatedDeliveryTime: { type: Number, required: true },
  cuisines: [{ type: String, required: true }],
  menuItems: [menuItemSchema],
  imageUrl: { type: String, required: true },
  lastUpdated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

const Restaurant = mongoose.model("Restaurant", restaurantSchema);

Controller Code:
const updateMyRestaurant = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    // Log incoming request data
    console.log("Request body before update:", req.body);

    const restaurant = await Restaurant.findOne({ user: req.userId });

    if (!restaurant) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "Restaurant not found" });
    }

    // Update fields
    restaurant.restaurantName = req.body.restaurantName;
    restaurant.city = req.body.city;
    restaurant.country = req.body.country;
    restaurant.deliveryPrice = req.body.deliveryPrice;
    restaurant.estimatedDeliveryTime = req.body.estimatedDeliveryTime;
    restaurant.cuisines = req.body.cuisines;
    restaurant.menuItems = req.body.menuItems;
    restaurant.lastUpdated = new Date(); 

    if (req.file) {
      const imageUrl = await uploadImage(req.file as Express.Multer.File);
      restaurant.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    await restaurant.save();
    res.status(200).send(restaurant);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error during restaurant update:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong" });
  }
};

I expected the lastUpdated field to be set correctly and the update operation to succeed without any validation errors. I've tried the following:

Ensuring that lastUpdated is assigned a new Date() value before saving the document.

Logging the value of lastUpdated before calling save() to confirm that it is being set.

Double-checking the schema to ensure lastUpdated has a default value and is not marked as required.


Despite these efforts, the validation error persists, and the update fails. I'm hoping to get insights into what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it.

The problem is in the following line:
restaurant.lastUpdated = new Date(); 

The default date is the birth of Jesus (1.1.1 00:00:00) which is considered to not defined or empty. Change it to following:
restaurant.lastUpdated = Date.now; 


Thank you for the suggestion! I tried using restaurant.lastUpdated = Date.now; to assign the current timestamp, but I'm still encountering the same validation error: "Path lastUpdated is required."
It seems like the lastUpdated field is still not being recognized as set before the save operation. I've also tried using new Date() for the lastUpdated field, but the issue persists.
If anyone has further insights or suggestions on what might be causing this problem, I would greatly appreciate it.
Thanks again for your help!

After reviewing my code, I discovered that the issue was in my form validation schema on the frontend, where I was using zod with react-hook-form for validation. I had forgotten to include the lastUpdated field in the validation schema.
